# Is there any lock-free malloc under BSD/BSD-like license?

Tags: malloc

Like NBmalloc: http://www.cse.chalmers.se/research/group/dcs/nbmalloc.html

Or Maged M. Michael's malloc: http://www.research.ibm.com/people/m/michael/pldi-2004.pdf

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Jemalloc is BSD/BSD-like licensed. http://www.canonware.com/jemalloc/

There is also SuperMalloc which is licensed as dual GPL3/MIT https://github.com/kuszmaul/SuperMalloc

Can you say what is the meaning of "lock-free"?

Comment: And there is partial reimplementation of Michael's malloc under GPL (2007): https://github.com/scotts/michael (by authors of streamflow - https://github.com/scotts/streamflow)